# Facebook albums cover photo using latest facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We can fetch facebook photo albums details using garph API `{user-id}/albums`

```
      /*make API call*/
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),  //your fb AccessToken
                "/" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId() + "/albums",//user id of login user
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(final GraphResponse response) {
                }
        }).executeAsync();
```

Now i need to get cover photo of those albums and i know using garph API `{albums-id}/picture` we can do that.like below

```
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("type", "small"); //You use this to get a pre-specified size of picture.
            params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + id + "/picture",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    }
            }).executeAsync();
```

But we need to make a different API call for it.is there any way to get albums cover photo along with albums details ?

and also I'm getting less quality cover photos.

I have tried with all types from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/picture)

```
type : enum{thumbnail,small,album}
```

Comment: `/me/albums?fields=picture` – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields

Comment: Thank you CBroe you are saved my day.

Comment: What do you do in onComplete? I'm trying to get the photo url source but can't find any help on what to do in the onComplete method.

Comment: Pass album id to photos API like follows http://pastebin.com/GNjTdEkx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a larger image than `album`. That's the size you're seeing on the FB album overview page.

To get the data with one call, you have to use the [Field API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading) like this:

```
GET /mashable/albums?fields=id,name,picture.type(album)
```

[Try it yourself](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=mashable%2Falbums%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cpicture.type(album)&version=v2.5)

With the Android SDK, the code should be

```
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),  //your fb AccessToken
    "/" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId() + "/albums",//user id of login user
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(final GraphResponse response) {
    }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture.type(album)");

request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you Tobi :) well explained .